# using silverlight 4 in sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint

can i use silverlight 4 with .Net 2008 and sharepoint 2007?
If possible, What steps are necessary in order to host a Silverlight 4 application, in a web part, on Sharepoint Server 2007 ?

Answer (score 1):

I have only been working with Silverlight 4 on SharePoint 2010 but I cannot see a problem with using it on SharePoint 2007. All you need is an [object tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089(VS.95).aspx) that your webpart emits and in that it points the the XAP file. The XAP file you can deploy to a sub folder of /_layouts. The only issue though is that you have to update the XAP file in the WSP package for deployment each time you change something in the silverlight application. This is not necessary when using SharePoint 2010/Visual Studio 2010 where you can include the project output from the Silverlight project to a WSP package.

Kr., Bernd.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if SharePoint 2007 supports Silverlight 4, but here is how you would set up a Web Part for an older version of Silverlight: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627341(office.12).aspx